# Error: Document type does not allow elemnt "Link" here

Tags: validation, w3c-validation

There were 78 errors in my website (in [link](http://validator.w3.org/)) but I have solved almost many of the issues, but there are some which I'm  unable to find like this below code (I searched the PHP code of the below mentioned but I didn't find it. Can any help me

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='-css' href='http://www.fatwaa.com/wp-content/plugins/navayan-subscribe/default.css?ver=3.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

There is one more issue "document type does not allow element "STYLE" here `<style type="text/css">.fancybox-hidden{display:none}.rtl #fancybox-left{left:…`

Though I found it's code but I found the solution that style must be between  ..

But if you look at it's complete code (line 238 [here](http://pastebin.com/YyxNFhn0)) I'm unable to do that.. Can anyone help me? Where shall I add `<head>..` in second issue?

Thanks

Regards

Muhammad

Comment: Do you have a link to the validation results and the code? That would really help in finding the exact cause of the issue :)

Comment: Hello Andrew, Thanks for the quick response.. Here is the  [link]http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fatwaa.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 [/link].. May i know you are asking about which code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This element is in the `body` of your document, but it needs to be in the `head`:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='-css'  href='http://www.fatwaa.com/wp-content/plugins/navayan-subscribe/default.css?ver=3.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
```